# Grouping results in SQL Server 2005 using xquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery-sql, xquery

I am trying to extract data, to use in a rss feed for google base currently using SQL Server 2005.

There a few problems we have, which i hope can be solved!

1. namespaces
2. grouping

My current sql is as follows:

```
SELECT [xml].query('
<Item xmlns:g="a">
<Title>{ data(*/*/*/Title) }</Title>
<g:id>{ sql:column("ReportingCode") }</g:id>
</Item>
')
FROM esh_xml 
where [Xml].value('(/*/*/*/Attributes/Attribute[@Description="Category"][text()="MasterMix"])[1]','nvarchar(2000)') is not null
```

as output with the current query I get many thousands of results rows ie

```
<item xmlns:g="a"><title>blah blah</title><g:id>asdasd<g:id></item>
```

my desired output would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
      <channel>
            <title>Mastermixdigital.com Product Feed </title>
            <link> http://www.mysite.com/ </link>
            <description>mastermix latest release feed </description>
            <item xmlns:g="a">
                  <title>blah blah</title>
                  <g:id>asdasd<g:id>
            </item>
            <item xmlns:g="a">
                  <title>blah blah</title>
                  <g:id>asdasd<g:id>
            </item>
            <item xmlns:g="a">
                  <title>blah blah</title>
                  <g:id>asdasd<g:id>
            </item>
      </channel>
</rss>
```

Another thing I believe the execution of the query could be sped up by removing redundant nodes before searching through, and any tips on how i might go about this!

Many thanks

Comment: Namespaces and grouping can be done in pure XQuery. It's not posible to tell exactly how without input source. Database tables, columns, and all the no standard SQL invocation of XQuery engine will be specific for SLQ Server not full XQuery standard complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your xml structure or tables so I created a sample that shows what you can do.

Setup sample data, two rows with two items in xml for each row, one item in row one is duplicate with one item in row two.

```
declare @T table (ID int identity, [xml] xml)

insert into @T ([xml])
values ('
<root>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name 1</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Name 2</name>
  </item>
</root>
')

insert into @T ([xml])
values ('
<root>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name 1</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Name 3</name>
  </item>
</root>
')
```

Get id and name from all rows

```
select  
  r.i.value('id[1]', 'int') as id,
  r.i.value('name[1]', 'varchar(10)') as name
from @T as T
  cross apply T.[xml].nodes('root/item') r(i)
```

Result, four rows

```
id  name
1   Name 1
2   Name 2
1   Name 1
3   Name 3
```

Same query with duplicates removed

```
select distinct 
  r.i.value('id[1]', 'int') as id,
  r.i.value('name[1]', 'varchar(10)') as name
from @T as T
  cross apply T.[xml].nodes('root/item') r(i)
```

Result three rows

```
id  name
1   Name 1
2   Name 2
3   Name 3
```

Join the rows back to xml using for xml path, root

```
select distinct 
  r.i.value('id[1]', 'int') as id,
  r.i.value('name[1]', 'varchar(10)') as name
from @T as T
  cross apply T.[xml].nodes('root/item') r(i)  
for xml path('item'), root('root')
```

Result xml

```
<root>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name 1</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Name 2</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Name 3</name>
  </item>
</root>
```

With namespace

```
;with xmlnamespaces('a' as g)
select distinct 
  r.i.value('id[1]', 'int') as [g:id],
  r.i.value('name[1]', 'varchar(10)') as name
from @T as T
  cross apply T.[xml].nodes('root/item') r(i)  
for xml path('item'), root('root')
```

Result

```
<root xmlns:g="a">
  <item>
    <g:id>1</g:id>
    <name>Name 1</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <g:id>2</g:id>
    <name>Name 2</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <g:id>3</g:id>
    <name>Name 3</name>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: how could we go a step further and appy a namspace to your xml output only onto the root? so id could become <g:id>1</g:id>